# Generating UML using javadoc

Tags: java, android-studio, uml, javadoc, diagram

I'm currently working on my final project of computer science studies. Android studio project. 
I need an UML diagram that created by javadoc.
How do I generate an UML using javadoc?
Thanks.

Comment: *How do I generate an UML using javadoc?* You don't. That is not something that javadoc does. Javadoc is not a tool for creating UML diagrams. Javadoc is not a tool for creating any kind of diagram. Javadoc turns text comments into html manual pages (and indexes them). Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you don't but you can from sources. A lot of tool are able to reverse Java Code into UML (Class diagram mainly). Some of them allow you to generate documentation from this reversed UML model including UML diagram automotically generated and reversed Java Documentation.